# How it happened that the same thing called "Russian mountains" in America and "American mountains" in Russia?

Tags: etymology

How it happened that the same roller coaster type is called "Russian mountains" in America and "American mountains" in Russia?

Comment: It's obvious that in Russia, people avoid the term "Russian something" because almost everything around them is Russian, so the adjective would carry very little information. For the same reason, "American something" isn't a useful name in America. It's normal to put some information in the words - and a foreign country does bring some information. It can make you happier than here in Pilsen, Czechia, the American Avenue used to be called the Moscow Avenue before. It's normal, especially if one tends to change his allies periodically. ;-)

Comment: @Luboš Motl "people avoid the term "Russian something"" - not really. Russian vodka, Russian sausage, Russian milk etc.

Comment: No, they do avoid all these things in Russia - which is what I said. The brand "Russian Vodka", perhaps with some extra adjectives, is used almost entirely just in the West. It's just "vodka" in Russia - they have almost no foreign vodka, anyway, so there is no reason to add the word. Similarly, "Russian sausage" is known simply as "kolbasa" in Russia. I've never heard of "Russian milk" that would be a term.

Comment: @Luboš Motl totally wrong. There is Russian vodka in Russia, also Russian standard vodka, Rossiyskiy cheese, Russian milk, Russian kolbasa. There is a lot of kolbasa types in Russia, Russian kolbasa is like Doctorskaya kolbasa but with fat pieces.

Comment: Fine, so they don't avoid this terminology strictly, but they still avoid it.

Comment: @Luboš Motl how do you conclude that? Actually brands containing "Russian" are very widespread in Russia, I think it is the most common type or brands.

Answer (score 2):

[The English Wiki says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roller_coaster#Russian_mountain): "The oldest roller coasters are believed to have originated from the so-called "Russian Mountains", which were specially constructed hills of ice, located especially around Saint Petersburg. Built in the 17th century, the slides were built to a height of between 21 and 24 m (70 and 80 feet), consisted of a 50 degree drop, and were reinforced by wooden supports.
Some historians say the first roller coaster was built under the orders of Russia's Catherine the Great in the Gardens of Oranienbaum in Saint Petersburg in the year 1784. Other historians believe that the first modern roller coaster was built by the French. ... The name *Russian Mountains* to designate a roller coaster is preserved in most Latin languages."

And [the Russian Wiki says](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8#.D0.98.D1.81.D1.82.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.8F): "Термин «американские горки» используется в России потому, что в виде, близком к современному, они были впервые сконструированы в США и получили там очень широкое распространение." — 'The term *American Mountains* is used in Russia since the roller coaster as it usually looks now was first constructed and built in the USA and got very popular there.'

Answer (score 2):

This is not the only example of the linguistic phenomenon whereby language A qualifies some object as B, while language B qualifies the same object as A. English uses “French letters” for “condoms”, while on the other side of the Channel they are called “capotes anglaises”.